# Unix - Sort particular output

Tags: linux, unix, sorting, csv

I need to sort this output:

```
/dir1NameWithSpaces/dir2NameWithSpaces/dir3NameWithSpaces/File1_04092008/es3.sml: some content .... with words and symbols
/dir1NameWithSpaces/dir2NameWithSpaces/dir3NameWithSpaces/File1_05012004/es3.sml: some content .... with words and symbols
/dir1NameWithSpaces/dir2NameWithSpaces/dir3NameWithSpaces/File1_24072010/es3.sml: some content .... with words and symbols
/dir1NameWithSpaces/dir2NameWithSpaces/dir3NameWithSpaces/File1_05012004/es3.sml: some content .... with words and symbols
```

Based on the year of the date like this "05012004" that would be "ggmmyyyy" so based on "yyyy".

So in the following way it's sorted:

```
/dir1NameWithSpaces/dir2NameWithSpaces/dir3NameWithSpaces/File1_05012004/es3.sml: some content .... with words and symbols
/dir1NameWithSpaces/dir2NameWithSpaces/dir3NameWithSpaces/File1_05012004/es3.sml: some content .... with words and symbols
/dir1NameWithSpaces/dir2NameWithSpaces/dir3NameWithSpaces/File1_04092008/es3.sml: some content .... with words and symbols
/dir1NameWithSpaces/dir2NameWithSpaces/dir3NameWithSpaces/File1_24072010/es3.sml: some content .... with words and symbols
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to extract the sort key, sort the lines and remove the sort key with `cut`:

```
sed -e 's/^.*[0-9]\{4\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1,&/' |
sort |
cut -d, -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the -k option with sort:

```
sort -t '/' -k5.11
```